# supervisord and crashmail - use environment variable in subject

Tags: docker, supervisord

I have a crashmail section set up in my supervisord.conf file:

```
[eventlistener:crashmail]
command=crashmail -o hostname --any -m user@email.com
stdout_logfile = /var/log/crashmail.log
events=PROCESS_STATE_EXITED
```

Since I have a number of docker containers, I would like to be able to pass the hostname in the subject or body of the crashmail email.

Is there a way to reference an environment variable like $HOSTNAME in the -o option?

I know I could use docker cp to edit the supervisord.conf file, but I would prefer to have a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to add:

```
-o %(ENV_HOSTNAME)s
```

to the crashmail command, e.g.:

```
[eventlistener:crashmail]
command=crashmail -o %(ENV_HOSTNAME)s --any -m user@email.com
stdout_logfile = /var/log/crashmail.log
events=PROCESS_STATE_EXITED
```

This is per the supervisord documentation:

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#environment-variables